# JDK API documentation is incorrect for ArrayList constructor. Is that a bug?

Tags: java, arraylist, documentation

JDK doc for [ArrayList constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList--) says that the initial capacity is 10.

This is actually wrong as the initial capacity is 0 till something is added to the list. I checked the source of Open JDK as well as the src.zip that comes with JDK.

I understand that this is a performance optimization but would this be considered a bug?

Comment: +1 You found a bug on the java documentation. As explained in my answer the new code is valid from java 7 but the documentation has not been updated.

Comment: Depends on where you draw the line. You could just as well argue that it's a lazy initialization of the class. Note that *no* array is allocated in the default constructor.

Comment: I proposed a new bug to Oracle. When the bug id will be available I will post it.

Comment: Weirdly related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290620/how-to-handle-links-to-external-resources-like-grepcode-or-docjar-or-the-openjd (At least, both links are still working :D )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Valid only for JDK up to 6**

It is not an error.

The initial capacity of the internal array used to store the elements of the list is really 10.

It not means that the size of the list is 10. Only that an empty array of size 10 is created.

When an object is added to the list an internal pointer to the last element is moved one over. If the capacity of the array is not sufficient another array is created with an higher capacity and the old array is copied in the first part of the new array. In this moment the capacity of the array is not more 10.

The code is:

```
public ArrayList() {
    this(10);   // Here the 10 of the default capacity
}

public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
    super();
    if (initialCapacity < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                                                initialCapacity);
    this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
}
```

---

**For newer JDK (from java 1.7)**

**Important NOTE:** Yes in the newer versions of `ArrayList` (I think from Java7) **the source code has changed**. **The documentation remains the old one**. So yes *it is a bug on the documentation*!

Here the new version of constructor

```
private static final Object[] EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA = {};

....

public ArrayList() {
    super();
    this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;  // This is 0 capacity!!!!
}
```

---

**NOTE:** I opened a new bug to Oracle to review the documentation.

Comment: take a look at the souce-code. The constructor `ArrayList()` contains this line: `this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;`, with `EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA` defined here: `private static final Object[] EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA = {};`. The empty array isn't of size 10, but 0, as OP said

Comment: I added the source code of ArrayList() and ArrayList(int initialCapacity)

Comment: What version is this? In 1.8 the constructor is coded the way I mentioned in my first comment

Comment: Did you get the bug id?

Comment: I have only the review ID at the moment: JI-9026540. This is not the bug id.

Answer (score 1):

It's a mistake in the documentation. They forgot to update the comment.

JDK 7 :

```
 public ArrayList() {
     this(10);
 }
```

JDK 8 :

```
/**
 * Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.
 */
public ArrayList() {
    super();
    this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
}
```

Comment: `EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA` is an `Object[]` of size 0. The initial capacity is 0, not 10.

Comment: It happened somewhere in one of the minor updates of JDK 7. I am using JDK 7 update 75 and the 10 is not present.

Comment: @AseemBansal - I only saw diff between jdk7 and jdk8.

Answer (score 0):

from 1.7 They are saying that an ArrayList of default size 10  will be created after adding a first element into it.. it means ArrayList Object won't be created until we add an element into it, read the description given on 'elementData' variable(Any empty ArrayList with elementData == EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA will be expanded DEFAULT_CAPACITY{it is an int variable} when the first element is added.). Its like lazy instantiation.

In 1.6 even though we are not adding element to ArrayList it is creating 10 sized empty object array, its like eager instantiation..

```
 /**
 * Default initial capacity.
 */
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;

/**
 * Shared empty array instance used for empty instances.
 */
private static final Object[] EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA = {};


 /*
 * The array buffer into which the elements of the ArrayList are stored.
 * The capacity of the ArrayList is the length of this array buffer. Any
 * empty ArrayList with elementData == EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA will be expanded    
 * DEFAULT_CAPACITY when the first element is added.
 */

private transient Object[] elementData;
 /**
 * Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten. (they might have forgot to update this..)
 */
public ArrayList() {
    super();
    this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
}
 /*
```